# What is this type of garden appliance power socket?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, powertools

I've inherited a garden shredder with a missing power cable.

The missing cable plugs into this large 3-pin socket on the body of the shredder where the earth pin is female, and the other two are male.

Googling the make of shredder isn't giving me anything useful. Neither is searching for general garden power extensions etc..

The shredder is from a German manufacturer called Atika, but I am in the UK and it is rebranded as Parkside. I have no idea where the product was purchased.

If it helps, this video shows the power cable being inserted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vc36GJsqw0&t=6

Does it look proprietary? Tips appreciated so I know what to search for.

[image]

Comment: Where in the world do you live? Plugs have regional variants

Comment: I'm in the UK, but it looks like the product is German. However, I have no idea whether the product was purchased in the UK.

Comment: This reminds me of what we would call a "hedge trimmer" in the US.  They typically do not have their own cords but instead have a shrouded male connector you are supposed to use your own extension cord with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [CEE 7/7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEE_7_standard_AC_plugs_and_sockets) plug often found in mainland Europe used in their sockets. It's for 220V on the male plugs (polarity doesn't matter) and ground to the female.

You should be able to find sockets for those online that you can wire to the female end of a (220V) extension cord.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered that the "socket" on the unit was actually a "plug". i.e. male and not female.

Answer (score 1):

A  lot of garden tools like this have a connector like this in France, and obviously Germany. The cable will have what's essentially a socket at one end, and a plug (which terminates in something similar to the pic) at the other. In France, they're sold as extension cables. Also available as connections to wire onto a cable end. Readily available on Ebay. CEE7/5 and CEE7/6 will also fit. The female is the French earth 'pin', while the German version has an earth connector external.